# JQuery script is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created the following JQuery script and it seems to work in all browsers except IE 8. When I viewed Internet Explorers error details I did not get any error details at all. IE just points to my JQuery file without showing the line of code that's affected. Any suggestions? I am using version 1.4.4 of JQuery 
My script is below

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("input[name='emailAddress']").blur(function() {
            // Actual Email Validation function
            $('#emailMessage').html("");
            var hasError = false;
            var emailaddressVal = $("input[name='emailAddress']").val().trim();
            var invalidEmailAddresses = ['goddady.com', 'aol.com', 'yahoo.com', 'yahoo.fr'];

            if(!isValidEmailAddres(emailaddressVal)) {
                $("<span id='emailMessage' class='LV_validation_message LV_invalid'>The email provided does not contain an @ symbol</span>").insertAfter("input[name='emailAddress']");
                hasError = true;
            } else {
                emailaddressVal = emailaddressVal.split('@').slice(1)[0].trim();

                if($.inArray(emailaddressVal, invalidEmailAddresses) >= 0) {
                    $("<span id='emailMessage' class='validation'>The email provided is not from a business related domain. Please use an appropriate email address instead.</span>").insertAfter("input[name='emailAddress']");
                } else {
                    $('#emailMessage').css('display', 'none');
                }
            }
            if(hasError == true) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        function isValidEmailAddres(emailID) {
            var regexExp = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
            return regexExp.test(emailID);
        }

    });
```

Comment: And what is the used jQuery version?

Comment: @Satpal You mean jQuery 2.0 doesn't work in IE<9?

Comment: @Teemu Good question I am using version 1.4.4 of JQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am suspecting the [`.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) as it's not supported on <=IE8. You'd be better off using [`jQuery.trim()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) as you're using `jQuery` anyway. For instance:

```
var emailaddressVal = $.trim($("input[name='emailAddress']").val());
```

Comment: So should I also replace emailaddressVal = emailaddressVal.split('@').slice(1)[0].trim(); ? Because when I type in an  invalid email address my invaild email address error message doesn't show up.

Comment: Not necessary I guess as the value has already been trimmed. But, doesn't harm trying and removing later as needed.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any idea why the  following piece of code is not executing:            if($.inArray(emailaddressVal, invalidEmailAddresses) >= 0) {
                    $("<span id='emailMessage' class='validation'>The email provided is not from a business related domain. Please use an appropriate email address instead.</span>").insertAfter("input[name='emailAddress']");
                } else {
                    $('#emailMessage').css('display', 'none');
                }

Comment: What doesn't work please? Put an alert inside that `if` and see if it appears.

Comment: well the following if($.inArray(emailaddressVal, invalidEmailAddresses) >= 0) should throw and error (see code above). I added an Alert after the statement above. The alert executes in Chrome, and Firefox but now in IE

Comment: Not sure why! but, you could simply use `emailaddressVal.split('@').pop()` as opposed to `emailaddressVal.split('@').slice(1)[0]`.

Comment: Nevermind I just found the issue. It was what you mentioned before I was trimming emailaddressVal twice I removed .trim() and now it works fine! For example emailaddressVal = emailaddressVal.split('@').slice(1)[0]; Thanks!